# Is it possible to get an indexed iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

Many languages allow iterating over an iterable data type, keeping track of its position as it iterates. For example...

Python:

```py
for index, value in enumerate(some_list):
    ...
```

Ruby/Crystal:

```rb
some_list.each_with_index do |value, index|
  ...
end
```

Rust:

```rust
for (value, index) in some_iterable.enumerate() {
    ...
}
```

etc, etc.

Depending on the iterator, it may be inefficient as well to simply use a plain for loop:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < some_list.size(); i++) {
    auto value = some_list[i];
}
```

Is there any way that C++ offers to express a similar concept?

Comment: I think there is no such built-in structure but it should be pretty simple to implement it. You could create an iterator that return the element with its index in a pair or you could use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any standard way of doing this but boost provides:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indexed.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::assign;
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> input;
    input += 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90;

    for (const auto& element : input | indexed(0))
    {
        std::cout << "Element = " << element.value()
                  << " Index = " << element.index()
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This example is taken [from the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html).